# Getting complicated about foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am a beginner in innoDB and not very good in database. I m getting confused about foreign keys. I just want to know is:

- If I delete a PK( fk on another table)

  - is the FK on child table also deleted?
  - So how about if I delete FK on child table?
  - Record in parent table also deleted?
- Also, if I ADD a new record to parent table

  - child table also added?
  - How about i add to child table?
  - How about if i update data?

Please help me, I am very confused about foreign key reference in innoDB database . Guide me to the easiest way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your'e asking about is cascading the update/deletion to the child element.

The docs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Example :
`CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`jobAbbr`) REFERENCES`ffxi_jobType`(`jobAbbr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

the "ON DELETE CASCADE" means that when the key is deleted, all the FK's are deleted aswell, this is very useful for data integrity. It's however not automatic.

Deleting a foreign key will not delete the key it's based upon either way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the foreign key constraints are defined, supported by the storage engine and are enabled, (i.e. MySQL variable `foreign_key_checks = 1`, Oracle foreign key constraints enabled and not deferred, etc.)

**Q:** If I delete a PK( fk on another table) , is the FK on child table also deleted ?

**A:** If the DELETE rule is specified as CASCADE, then a delete on the parent table will also perform delete operation on the child table. If the DELETE rule is specified as RESTRICT, and there's rows in the child table that reference the parent key, then the DELETE operation will raise an error.

(*EDIT:* For the sake of completeness, we note that "SET NULL" is another option for an UPDATE or DELETE rule.)

**Q:** If I delete a row from the child table with a reference to a row in the parent table, is the row in the parent table also deleted ?

**A:** No. Deleting rows in the child table will have no affect on row in the parent table.

**Q:** If I INSERT a new row to parent table, will a row also be added to the child table>

**A:** No. Rows are *not* automatically inserted to child tables. It's valid (relational database-wise) to have a parent row that does not have any child rows referencing it.

**Q:** If I INSERT a row to the child table ?

**A:** No. An insert to the child table does not automatically insert a row to the parent table. (Any non-null value of the foreign key column being inserted to the child table will be validated; the database will verify that there already exists a row in the parent table with a matching value. If there's not, then the INSERT will fail with an error.)

**Q:** What if I UPDATE values of the foreign key column in the child table.

**A:** Same as with an insert, the new value will be validated before the update operation proceeds.

**Q:** What if I UPDATE the value of the primary key in the parent table?

**A:** If the UPDATE rule on the foreign key is specified as `CASCADE`, then the related rows in the child table will also be updated, to preserve the relationship between the rows. If the UPDATE rule is `RESTRICT`, and there are related rows in the child table, the update operation will raise an error.

---

Foreign keys are designed for enforcing referential integrity. They basically disallow inserts/updates in the child table when the new non-null values of the foreign key column doesn't reference a row in the parent.

The UPDATE and CASCADE rules defined on the foreign key constraint determine the behavior of UPDATE and DELETE operations on the parent table.

Comment: How about if the foreign key property is default ?? I mean i never specified CASCADE or RESTRICT ?

Comment: If you don't specify a DELETE or UPDATE rule on the foreign key, I think the behavior depends on the database. In MySQL InnoDB, the default is "NO ACTION" which is effectively equivalent to "RESTRICT". I believe Oracle is the same, the default rule is effectively the same as "RESTRICT".

Comment: Cascade is generally a poor idea, don't use it unless you know  that itwon't cause problems. You would want to be prevented from deleting a customer if he had orders that shoudl not be deleted . It is also a sign of bad design if you have a PK that would need updating. Then you would need to update all child records as well and if you haad a million of them associated to one PK in the parent table that could be very messy and lock up your database. There are times when an updateable PK is OK but don't do it until you are a database expert and have the judgement you need to make the call.